# Overlapping views and drag events

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have two overlapping views which both consume the same drag event.  Think a small circle under a much larger one.  When the touch location cross over the smaller circle which is under (in zdepth) the larger one it triggers a `ACTION_DRAG_EXITED` event, even though the view's bounds have not been exited.  The event is effectively hopping from the higher view to the lower view.

How can I prevent the lower view from triggering events when occluded?

thanks!
Nigel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else encounters this, to fix it I used `view.bringToFront()` to ensure the larger circle view was on top.  Interestingly even though it was *drawing* on top and its elevation was higher, android didn't consider it on top in the context of the drag event.